# Find the limit of $n^{2} ( \sqrt[n]{x} - \sqrt[n+1]{x} )$ as $x \to \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, analysis

We are tasked with evaluating this limit
$$\lim_{x\to \infty} n^{2} ( \sqrt[n]{x} - \sqrt[n+1]{x} )$$

As opposed to quite a lot of variants of this limit, for this one, the one that involves in the limit is $n$, not $x$. So we can make $n^2$ quite irrelevant in this case, so
$$\lim_{x\to \infty} n^{2} ( \sqrt[n]{x} - \sqrt[n+1]{x} )= n^{2} \lim_{x\to \infty} ( \sqrt[n]{x} - \sqrt[n+1]{x} )$$

Here, I tried to solve for $\lim_{x\to \infty} ( \sqrt[n]{x} - \sqrt[n+1]{x} )$. The only method I could think of is using the identity $$x^n - y^n = (x-y)(x^{n-1} + x^{n-2} y + ... + x y^{n-2} + y^{n-1})$$ Then we have
$$
\begin{split}
\lim_{x\to \infty} ( \sqrt[n]{x} - \sqrt[n+1]{x} ) &= \lim_{x\to \infty} ( \sqrt[n]{x}-1+1 - \sqrt[n+1]{x} ) \\
& = \lim_{x\to \infty} ( \sqrt[n]{x}-1) - \lim_{x\to \infty} (\sqrt[n+1]{x} - 1) \\
& = \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{( \sqrt[n]{x}-1)[ (\sqrt[n]{x})^{n-1} + \cdots + 1 ]}{[(\sqrt[n]{x})^{n-1} + \cdots + 1 ]} - \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{( \sqrt[n+1]{x}-1)[ (\sqrt[n+1]{x})^{n} + \cdots + 1 ]}{[(\sqrt[n+1]{x})^{n} + \cdots + 1 ]}
\end{split}
$$

This reduces to
$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{x-1}{[(\sqrt[n]{x})^{n-1} + \cdots + 1 ]} - \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{x-1}{[(\sqrt[n+1]{x})^{n} + \cdots + 1 ]}$$

Now, I have some confusions with this one. So my current situation is that I believe that the denominator will always go to bigger and bigger, to $\infty$, as far as $n > 0$, and perhaps most of the time, my assumption is that $$[(\sqrt[n+1]{x})^{n} + \cdots + 1 ] \geq x - 1$$ so the fraction in total will go to $0$ as far as the assumption is given as such.

But when I approach this problem in another way, which is by rewrite the whole limit as $$n^2(\lim_{x\to\infty} x^\frac1n - x^\frac{1}{n+1})$$ Using that $$ x^{\frac1n}=e^{\frac{\ln{x}}{n}}$$ The limit becomes $$n^2 \lim_{x\to\infty} (e^{\frac{\ln{x}}{n}} - e^{\frac{\ln{x}}{n+1}})$$ of which as long as $n$ does not reach $\infty$, the limit goes to infinity, which is contradictory to what the way we have done above results in, given the assumption.

I am pretty sure that there are faults, but I do not know how to clearly approach and fix those issues. I also tried to disprove the assumption, but I do not know how. How would I proceed then to solve this limit? Where I am wrong at?

Comment: The factor $n^2$ can be ignored, unless you want the limit as $n\to\infty.$

Comment: I would let $y=x^{1/(n(n+1))},$ then this becomes $$n^2\lim_{y\to\infty}\left(y^{n+1}-y^n\right)$$ which is obviously $+\infty.$

Comment: What if $n<0$ or so? Maybe we should have two or three cases depends on $n$'s value?

Comment: You should state that $n$ is a positive integer (unless you mean differently then state that).  I made some minor edits but this is now solved below.

Comment: I think I should, because the original question does not contain anything about how $n$ should be. Thanks!

Comment: But how ... ? Is this notation $\sqrt [-5]{x}$ meaningful ? I think that the notation forces that $n>0$ .

Comment: If you switch it back to $x^{\frac{m}{n}}$, it still has some meanings, right?

Comment: $\lim (x_n-y_n)=\lim x_n-\lim y_n$ only when the right hand limits exist and one of them is finite.

Comment: Also, why in you answer did $-$ become $+?$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How would I proceed then to solve this limit?

Let $x=u^{n(n+1)}$ as $u\to\infty$, where $n>0$, then we have :

$$
\begin{align}\lim_{u\to \infty}n^2(u^{n+1}-u^n)=\lim_{u\to \infty}n^2u^n(u-1)\to\infty . \end{align}
$$